# How use my docker-compose configuration with gitlab CI

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project on gitlab, and I would use gitlab CI for unit testing.
Actually, I have a other repository name "docker" with docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile for two project (because i reproduce the production configuration, the two project are interdependant)

**Actually in my dev configuration**

in Projects directory:

- docker
- project_1
- project_2

in docker directory:

- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile-project1
- Dockerfile-project2
- [some config file ask in dockerFile]

docker-compose.yml have relative path  as ../project_1 and  ../project_2

For set up my configuration, I make :

- cd docker
- docker-compose up -d project1 (name in docker-compose.yml)
- docker exec -ti project1 bash

**Question ?**
I want know how I can pull the  git repository "docker" and launch docker-compose up  for the project1 since gitlab CI start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've built a [gitlab runner with docker-compose](https://github.com/schmunk42/docker-gitlab-runner) support. See its README for setup and configuration.

Basically you just use the same commands like in development, see [here](https://github.com/dmstr/phd5-app/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) for an example with Makefiles or [this one](https://github.com/dmstr/docker-yii2-app/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) with native `docker-compose` commands.